# Using LINQ to read key value pair from configuration file

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a file with some key pair values

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[section name]
key3 = value3
key4 = value4
```

so I don't care about section names as the keys are unique. I just want to get the the value for an input key. I have the following to read the lines.

```
  var userDataLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
```

and I have something like this

```
 var result = userDataLines.Select(userDataLine => userDataLine.Split(new[] { '=' }))
                           .Where(split => split.Length == 2);
```

gives me all the key value pairs in one collection.

but essentially I want to get a dictionary with keys and values from my file but not sure how to do that. Can anyone poing me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ToDictionary Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) as follows:

```
var result = File.ReadLines(pathToFile)
                 .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2))
                 .Where(split => split.Length == 2)
                 .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

(Small improvements: use [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) instead of [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), and  split each line into [at most 2 parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx).)

Answer (score 2):

There's a LINQ extension method for this:

```
var result = userDataLines.Select(userDataLine => userDataLine.Split(new[] { '=' }))
                           .Where(split => split.Length == 2)
                           .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ToDictionary` extension method and tell it what element is the key and which is the value:

```
var dictionary = userDataLines.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { '=' }))
                    .Where(x => x.Length == 2)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from a in userDataLines
              let pairs = a.Split('=')
              where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && !a.Trim().StartsWith("[")
              select new { Key = pairs[0].Trim(), Value = pairs[1].Trim() });
```

I find Linq easier to read, and i wasn't aware of the ToDictionary method!