# Using LINQ to build a Dictionary from a List of delimited strings

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a list of strings that look like this:

```
abc|key1|486997
def|key1|488979
ghi|key2|998788 
gkl|key2|998778
olz|key1|045669
```

How can I use LINQ and ToDictionary to produce a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` that looks like

```
key1 : { abc|key1|486997, def|key1|488979, olz|key1|045669 }
key2 : { ghi|key2|998788, gkl|key2|998778 }
```

Basically I want to be able to extract the second element as the key use ToDictionary() to create the dictionary in one go-round.

I'm currently doing this ..

```
 var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            foreach(var l in values)
            {
                var b = l.Split('|');
                var k = b.ElementAtOrDefault(1);

                if (!d.ContainsKey(k))
                    d.Add(k, new List<string>());

                d[k].Add(l);
            }
```

I've seen the questions on building dictionaries from a single string of delimited values, but I'm
wondering if there's an elegant way to do this when starting with a list of delimited strings instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400213/using-linq-to-read-key-value-pair-from-configuration-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var list = new []
{
"abc|key1|486997",
"def|key1|488979",
"ghi|key2|998788",
"gkl|key2|998778",
"olz|key1|045669"
};

var dict = list.GroupBy(x => x.Split('|')[1])
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

You can also transform it to a lookup (that is very similary to a `Dictionary<K,IEnumerable<V>>`) in one shot:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Split('|')[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I ended up figuring out.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is guaranteed to be consistent like that, you could do something like this:

```
var data = new[]
                {
                    "abc|key1|486997",
                    "def|key1|488979",
                    "ghi|key2|998788",
                    "gkl|key2|998778",
                    "olz|key1|045669"
                };
var items = data
            .GroupBy(k => k.Split('|')[1])
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new[]
                {
                    "abc|key1|486997",
                    "def|key1|488979",
                    "ghi|key2|998788",
                    "gkl|key2|998778",
                    "olz|key1|045669"
                };
var dictionary = data.Select(row => row.Split('|'))
  .GroupBy(row =>  row[1])
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group);
```

Comment: That will return a `Dictionary<string, IGrouping<string, string[]>>`

Comment: @vcsjones Yes, yes it will.  The OP didn't specify a desired type, so we don't know how he'll want to use it.

Comment: Quoting OP: *How can I use LINQ and ToDictionary to produce a **Dictionary<string, List<string>>***